# Python3.5 erorr when import easygui

Tags: python, easygui

I got below error when import easygui in Python3.5

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    import easygui
  File "C:\Users\bhongtip\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\easygui-0.98.0-py3.5.egg\easygui\__init__.py", line 50, in <module>
    from .boxes.choice_box import choicebox
  File "C:\Users\bhongtip\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\easygui-0.98.0-py3.5.egg\easygui\boxes\choice_box.py", line 76
    except Exception, e:
                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: It is probably because the module was written in Python 2.x

Answer (score 3):

This issue was fixed in EasyGUI 0.98.1, which [includes the change I suggested in my original answer below](https://github.com/robertlugg/easygui/commit/68b9116dc40ad2c3575d810c2dbb7611cbe4aeab).

If you are still encountering this issue, upgrade to the latest release with

```
pip install -U "easygui>=0.98.1"
```

---

*My original answer*:

EasyGUI 0.98 [introduced a change incompatible with Python 3](https://github.com/robertlugg/easygui/commit/b5eab34c021d1d6eb5e51b67b81da6dbee56e94a).

You'll need to either downgrade to 0.97.4 (`pip install -U EasyGUI==0.97.4`) or fix that change.

Fixing that line is as easy as replacing line 76:

```
except Exception, e:
```

with

```
except Exception as e:
```

This is tracked as [issue #97](https://github.com/robertlugg/easygui/issues/97) by the project (with duplicates [#101](https://github.com/robertlugg/easygui/issues/101) and [#102](https://github.com/robertlugg/easygui/issues/102), and pull requests [#100](https://github.com/robertlugg/easygui/pull/100), [#103](https://github.com/robertlugg/easygui/pull/103), [#105](https://github.com/robertlugg/easygui/pull/105) and [#107](https://github.com/robertlugg/easygui/pull/107)).

Answer (score 0):

I see the easygui you have is for python 2.7.there are 2 things you can do.

1. go to the `C:\Users\bhongtip\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\easygui-0.98.0-py3.5.egg\easygui\boxes\choice_box.py` and change the line to `except (Exception, e):` but that wouldn't solve all the problems.
2. open cmd and type `pip3 uninstall easygui` then after that has been run type `pip3 install --user easygui` that should install the correct version for your python 3.5

Comment: Yes, the problem has *long* since been fixed. Installing the current version is certainly preferable.

Comment: Note that your suggested edit to my post was wrong, see [Python - except (OSError, e) - No longer working in 3.3.3?](//stackoverflow.com/q/20517785) for why the change you made would break code.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried using:

```
from easygui import *
```

this is what I have always used and uhave used choicebox before.